# VBScript Find a node in XML node and replace the value

Tags: vbscript

How to write a `vbscript` which should search for a specific node in a XML file and replace the value of that node with another value?

So far I can read a node and get the value.

```
set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.async = "false"
objXML.load("E:\sage2\test.xml")
Set Root = objXML.documentElement

For Each x In Root.childNodes

 if x.nodename="showList" then
    plot=x.text
    msgbox plot
 end if
Next
```

please suggest me some example which should read a specific node in the xml file and replace the value of that node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a simple XML edit and save example in VBScript. I recommend lokking into using Xpath to select your node instead of looping over the child nodes, you can provide your XML for more detailed answer.

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.load "MYFILE.xml"

'Locate the desired node
'Note the use of XPATH instead of looping over all the child nodes
Set nNode = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//parentnode/targetnode")

'Set the node text with the new value
nNode.text = "NEW VALUE"

'Save the xml document with the new settings.
strResult = xmldoc.save("MYFILE.xml")
```

Comment: -0.5 for using the .save method (a plain Sub) as a function that returns a string.