# VBS search XML node by attribute name, change child attribute

Tags: xml, vbscript

this is a stripped down version of my XML file: simple.xml

```
<project>
 <scenes>
  <scene>
   <rootgroup>
    <nodelist>
     <module type="WRITE" name="Write_1080P">
      <option>
       <disabled val="true"/>
      </option>
     </module>
    </nodelist>
   </rootgroup>
  </scene>
 </scenes>
</project>
```

I need a vbscript find the correct "module" node by it's attribute name="Write_1080p" and then change the attribute "val" of his child node "disabled".

Should be quite simple, but I'm new to scripting in VB and am about to have a seizure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching XML using VBS and changing a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726266/searching-xml-using-vbs-and-changing-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

This script:

```
  Dim oFS    : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sFSpec : sFSpec   = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\testdata\xml\so11781815.xml")
  Dim oXML   : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  oXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  oXML.async = False
  oXML.load sFSpec
  If 0 = oXML.parseError Then
     WScript.Echo oXML.xml
     WScript.Echo "-----------------"
     Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "/project/scenes/scene/rootgroup/nodelist/module[@name=""Write_1080P""]/option/disabled"
     Dim ndFnd  : Set ndFnd = oXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
     If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
        WScript.Echo sXPath, "not found"
     Else
        WScript.Echo ndFnd.nodeName, ndFnd.getAttribute("val")
        WScript.Echo "-----------------"
        ndFnd.setAttribute "val", "disabled"
        WScript.Echo oXML.xml
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo oXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

output:

```
<project>
        <scenes>
                <scene>
                        <rootgroup>
                                <nodelist>
                                        <module type="WRITE" name="Write_1080P">
                                                <option>
                                                        <disabled val="true"/>
                                                </option>
                                        </module>
                                </nodelist>
                        </rootgroup>
                </scene>
        </scenes>
</project>

-----------------
disabled true
-----------------
<project>
        <scenes>
                <scene>
                        <rootgroup>
                                <nodelist>
                                        <module type="WRITE" name="Write_1080P">
                                                <option>
                                                        <disabled val="disabled"/>
                                                </option>
                                        </module>
                                </nodelist>
                        </rootgroup>
                </scene>
        </scenes>
</project>
```

shows how to use `.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"` to make sure that XPath queries are processed, how to query for an attribute value (`..t/module[@name=""Write_1080P""]/opt..`), and how to read (`.getAttribute("val")`) and write (`.setAttribute "val", "disabled"`) an attribute.

**P.S.**
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11728542/603855) to see how you can look for/change text (with essentially the same code).

Comment: Magical! Thanks Ekkehard. Just needed to to add 'oXML.Save "simple.xml" ' to write to the file.