# how to replace @VARIABLE in text file with value of Emails in xml file

Tags: vbscript

How i can read this xml file

```
<Subs>
  <Sub Report="BusinessSummarySubs" EMails="lalla@yahoo.com; haha@yahoo.com">
  <Sub Report="PlayerSubs" EMails="hehe@hotmail.com">
</Subs>
```

and replace @VARIABLE in BusinesSummarySubs.txt with EMails value in

Here is the content(part of the content) from BusinessSumarySubs.txt

```
CType(extensionParams(0),ParameterValue).Name = "TO"
CType(extensionParams(0),ParameterValue).Label = ""
CType(extensionParams(0),ParameterValue).Value = "@VARIABLE"
```

Comment: can anybody help me ?

Comment: Do you know how to read an XML file via VBScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11782233/603855), you'll see how to search for and to access attributes. Follow the link chain to ['the same for text'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11728542/603855) and do a mental diff, if you want to get a skeleton for a minimal XML processing script to use for your next task.

Single placeholder substitution in VBScript is easy: just use Replace:

```
>> attr = "lalla@yahoo.com; haha@yahoo.com"
>> content = "... .Value = ""@VARIABLE"" ..."
>> ph = "@VARIABLE"
>> WScript.Echo Replace(content, ph, attr)
>>
... .Value = "lalla@yahoo.com; haha@yahoo.com" ...
>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this i suposed

```
   set xmlDoc=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async="false"
xmlDoc.load("note.xml")

for each Emails in xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes
  document.write(Emails .nodename)
  document.write(": ")
  document.write(Emails .text)
next
```

Comment: "plot" not used, no Set when assigning to objNodeList, trying to get an attribute (EMails) via the .text property.